# Subdomain to Subdirectory Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to convert 'http://city.example.com' to 'http://www.example.com/city' in an Excel sheet.

I have tried a multi-step approach to first TRIM or SUBSTITUTE the prefix then the suffix, but I'm in over my head.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: I understand, thank you for the feedback.  I should have posted the formulas I referenced instead of just paraphrasing. This is a fantastic resource and following best practices is important.

Answer (score 0):

Do heed the comment regarding formulating a proper question and posting what you've tried and what is going wrong.

Either way, assuming your domains are in column A and there is only a single subdomain:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,FIND("//",A1,1)+2,FIND(".",A1,1)-(FIND("//",A1,1)+2)),"www")&MID(A1,FIND("//",A1,1)+2,FIND(".",A1,1)-(FIND("//",A1,1)+2))
```

[image]

Breaking it down into pieces:

- `FIND("//",A1,1)+2` will return the index of the start of the subdomain.
- `FIND(".",A1,1)` will return the index of the first period, the end of the subdomain.
- As such, the string from the start of the subdomain to the period will be the subdomain - since we're getting index's back we have to subtract them to get our MID length - `FIND(".",A1,1)-(FIND("//",A1,1)+2)`
- Chaining those together, we can say we want to substitute whatever is from the // to the first period with www. - `SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,FIND("//",A1,1)+2,FIND(".",A1,1)-(FIND("//",A1,1)+2)),"www")`
- This now leaves us with the subdomain replaced with www, so we just need to append the subdomain now, which we already know how to get - it's the mid formula we just used:
  `MID(A1,FIND("//",A1,1)+2,FIND(".",A1,1)-(FIND("//",A1,1)+2)`
- As such, we concatenate our two formulas together to get the result.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works great! I understand my error in posting my intital question and obvioulsy brevity wasn't on my side.  I'll make sure to post my actual results in my question in the future.